# Pyspark and error "TypeError: must be real number, not Column", when attempting to find compass bearing using a defined function over a window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, databricks

I am trying to apply a function that will find the compass bearing between two points, over a window in pyspark (using a community edition of Databricks). I am very new to spark and I'm sure I'm missing something.

**I have a test data frame that looks like this (borrowed it from a similar question and added a column called "bin"):**

```
Timestamp,User,Latitude,Longitude,bin,BID
1462838468,49B4361512443A4DA,39.777982,-7.054599,A1,49B4361512443A4DA A1
1462838512,49B4361512443A4DA,39.777982,-7.054599,A1,49B4361512443A4DA A1
1462838389,49B4361512443A4DA,39.777982,-7.054599,A1,49B4361512443A4DA A1
1462838497,49B4361512443A4DA,39.777982,-7.054599,A1,49B4361512443A4DA A1
1465975885,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,A1,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 A1
1457723815,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177322,-7.426781,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1457897289,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177922,-7.447443,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1457899229,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177922,-7.447443,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1457972626,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.18059,-7.46128,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1458062553,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177322,-7.426781,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1458241825,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.178172,-7.444512,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1458244457,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.178172,-7.444512,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1458412513,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177322,-7.426781,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1458412292,405C238E25FE0B9E7,37.177322,-7.426781,A1,405C238E25FE0B9E7 A1
1465197963,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
1465202192,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
1465923817,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
1465923766,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
1465923748,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
1465923922,6E9E0581E2A032FD8,37.118362,-8.205041,B2,6E9E0581E2A032FD8 B2
```

**These are the libraries:**

`from pyspark.sql.functions import acos, cos, sin, lit, toRadians`

`from pyspark.sql import functions as F`

`from pyspark.sql.window import Window`

`import math`

`from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, col, lit, lag, udf`

`from pyspark.sql.types import LongType`

**This is the function:**

```
def direction_lookup(destination_x, origin_x, destination_y, origin_y):

deltaX = destination_x - origin_x

deltaY = destination_y - origin_y

degrees_temp = math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY)/math.pi*180

if degrees_temp < 0:

    degrees_final = 360 + degrees_temp

else:

    degrees_final = degrees_temp


return degrees_final`
```

**I define the window using a concatenated column of "User" and "bin" (which I named "BID"), and order by timestamp:**

`w = Window().partitionBy("BID").orderBy("Timestamp")`

**Then I attempt to calculate bearing in degrees between each timestamp like this:**

`bearing_df = df2.withColumn("bearing", bearing("Longitude",  lag("Longitude", 1).over(w), "Latitude", lag("Latitude", 1).over(w)))`

The function works if I use just coordinates, so I'm doing something wrong in how I am applying it in spark. I have also used this same workflow successfully to calculate distance between points (obviously, with a different function). I have tried registering it as a UDF and I got the same error, "TypeError: must be real number, not Column". I'm not sure what to try next and I am very new to pyspark. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the example data from a csv file, I use `inferSchema` to get rid of the casts:

```python
df = spark.read.option("header", True).option("inferSchema", True).csv(...)
```

`df` has now the schema

```
root
 |-- Timestamp: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- User: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- bin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- BID: string (nullable = true)
```

Next the udf can be defined with

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
bearing = udf(direction_lookup, DoubleType())
```

Finally the udf can be called with the line in the question.

---

Two remarks only indirectly related to the question:

- the function `direction_lookup` should have a null check in the beginning. The `lag` function for the first row of a group returns `None` and calculation will fail otherwise

```python
def direction_lookup(destination_x, origin_x, destination_y, origin_y):
    if origin_x is None or origin_y is None:
        return None
    deltaX = destination_x - origin_x
    [...]
```

- the window spec also takes two rows for the definition of the partition (`w = Window().partitionBy("User","bin").orderBy("Timestamp")`) so the `BID` column is not strictly required

Comment: Thank you, just seeing this, I will give it a try tomorrow!

Comment: This worked!!! I'm so happy, thank you so much for taking the time to leave me such a great answer. I think it was the null check that got it working.

Answer (score 2):

columns in a dataframe are of type Column. When you are passing values function, Function is expecting a number type not column data type.

You can cast the values before passing to the function

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
data_df = data_df.withColumn("samplecol", data_df["samplecol"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: I had suspected this and tried this earlier. Just tried again and I am still getting the same error with this code: `bearing_df = df2.withColumn("bearing", bearing(df2["Longitude"].cast(DoubleType()), lag(df2["Longitude"].cast(DoubleType()), 1).over(w), df2["Latitude"].cast(DoubleType()), lag(df2["Latitude"].cast(DoubleType()), 1).over(w)))`